Web Workers Security Error: Content at X may not load data from Y
I wanted to use javascript web workers for multithreading but it throws the following:
Security Error: Content at X may not load data from Y

X is the index.html location and Y is worker.js.
I tried it in firefox (it gave the error above), chrome, edge and yandex (turns out the last 3 don't support WW at all), each on both windows 10 (with/without windows defender) and linux mint, but to no avail.
My project doesn't use any frameworks.
What should I do to make it work? Perhaps, there is a better way to implement multithreading in js?

This issue might appears if X and Y are location of different domain. I have a similar issue on firefox but a different error message on Chrome: Unhandled Navigation Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL X/foo cannot be created in a document with origin Y and URL Y/foo/bar. Not sure it could help you.

@Snook, thanks, but all the files are in the same folder on the desktop

You need to run a local server.
